# Unresolved Identifier Scope

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am new to Swift 3 and I have a problem with the following code:

```
func downloadData() {... downloads data about actors in JSON and initializes a Struct Actor}
```

then:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var dataArray = [Actor]() //declare an empty array of type Actor

     override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataArray = downloadData() //to populate an empty array with data downloaded from web

      print(dataArray)
```

When i try to compile the code I received the error Unresolved Identifier. I assume that it is because of the scope. Can anybody point me the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: We need more information to go on here. What identifier is unresolved? Where is the error happening?

Comment: Where do you define `downloadData()`? What does it return? Is it an asynchronous function as it downloads data from the Web? If yes, you need callbacks or delegates or alike.

Comment: Why do create a new array, assign it to `dataArray`, then immediately overwrite it with the result of `downloadData()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your function/method, `downloadData()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var dataArray = [Actor]() //declare an empty array of type Actor

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        dataArray = downloadData() //to populate an empty array with data downloaded from web

        print(dataArray)
    }

    func downloadData() -> [Actor] {

        return [Actor]()
    }
}
```

Just implement the downloadData method.
edit:
You can use EVReflection and Alamofire(Pods) to download json and create Actors and populate array.

Comment: when I try to populate an empty array `dataArray = downloadData()` I receive this error: Cannot assign value of type() to type [Actor].

Comment: are you sure there is "func downloadData() -> [Actor]" in your code?